# What's the NB30 or MM-TD in an iPhone description in GSX?

Tags: iphone

What's the NB30 or  MM-TD in an iPhone description?
I always see these nomenclatures Non block, etc, what does it mean?
[image]

Comment: Can you please add some examples/links/screenshots which show where exactly these things appear?

Comment: there it goes, this is in Apple GSX.  Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 6S exists in basically two versions:

Models A1687 and A1688 has support for LTE bands 1-5, 7-8, 12-13, 17-20 and 25-29

Models A1633 and A1634 has support for LTE bands 1-5, 7-8, 12-13, 17-20 and 26-30.

The extra band 30 is a special AT&T band. The iPhone supporting that band were sold by certain dealers in the US.

The NB30 on your iPhone description just means that you iPhone does not support LTE band 30.